# How to define generic type 'has property' constrint without type definition?

Tags: typescript, typescript4.0

Suppose we have to implement the following:

```
export class Class1<T> {
    public constructor(param1: T) {
        param1.prop1 = 1; // TS error: T doesn't have property 'prop1'
    } 
}
```

Given that we're unable to inherit all possible `param1` from a single base `interface``class``, how to constrain the `T`?

I've tried `T extends { prop1: number }`, but it's an incorrect syntax for TS.

Comment: It is actually valid: `export class Class1<T extends { prop1: number }> {`

Comment: @zerkms You're right. It seems I've had some issues with VS Code's built-in error checker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I've given in the question is correct:

```
export class Class1<T extends { prop1: number }> {
    public constructor(param1: T) {
        param1.prop1 = 1; // No TS error now
    } 
}
```

It seems I've had some issues with VS Code's built-in error checker.